# C# Read ini value from url

Tags: c#, web, ini

I have a site for example "http://example.com" and here is settings.ini file "http://example.com/settings.ini" , in file wrriten this text:

```
[Client]
Enabled=1
```

I wan't to give that value from C#, is it possible, how to?

For example I'm using this code:

```
var MyIni = new IniFile(@"C:\settings.ini");
var DefaultVolume = MyIni.Read("Enabled");
MessageBox.Show(DefaultVolume);
```

It works good, I'm trying to make something like this:

```
var MyIni = new IniFile(@"http://example.com/settings.ini");
```

but its not work, thanks.

EDIT:

I'm getting this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type "System.ArgumentException" in mscorlib.dll
For more information: URI formats are not supported.
```

Updated:

This code gets all value from .ini, now i need to integrate to my old code

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://example.com/settings.ini");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: i think its file  access permission related problem

Answer (score 0):

Read ini file content with HttpWebRequest (http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use my library in order to retrieve your settings from an INI file:

https://github.com/MarioZ/MadMilkman.Ini

For example like the following:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
IniFile myIni = new IniFile();

myIni.Load(client.OpenRead("http://example.com/settings.ini"));

string defaultVolume = myIni.Sections["Client"].Keys["Enabled"].Value;
MessageBox.Show(defaultVolume);
```

Also just as an FYI, you can retrieve that value as an integer like the following:

```
int volume;
myIni.Sections["Client"].Keys["Enabled"].TryParseValue(out volume);
```

I hope this helps.